# remap column name for foreign key in model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

So this is probably simple but I've been scouring the interwebs and have come up with nothing.

Assuming I have a customer table and a invoice table. The customer table has a one to many relationship with the invoice table. But the actual name of the foreign key in the invoice table is `cust_id` not the `customer_id` that Laravel expects. So when I set up a relationship in the model it fails with a `unknown column customer_id` How do I let laravel know what the actual column name is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.  You can find the docs on relationships [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships)

```
public function invoices() {
    return $this->hasMany('Invoice', 'cust_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Dang it. I knew it would be something simple like that, and that fact that it is repeated 3 times in the documentation just makes it that much worse. I swear I looked through there. Thank you kind Sir.